# FLAG_NO_CLEAR is ignored on Android 13

Tags: android, android-notifications

The behavior of the notification flag "FLAG_NO_CLEAR" ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat#FLAG_NO_CLEAR())) is different on **Android 13**.

On a Android 12 or lower device, the "*clear all*" button or a **swipe** does not remove the notification.
On Android **13** you **can swipe it away**, but it will be not removed on the "*clear all*" button.

Does Android 13 need any additional flag for "not removable"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Android 13 needs a different flag called "FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT" ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT()))!

The "FLAG_NO_CLEAR" also removed the ability to swipe a notification away before Android 13.
Now you need to use the "FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT" instead of "FLAG_NO_CLEAR" if you want both.